# Private push service

Tags: web-applications, push-notification

I have successfully implemented a Service Worker to push notification to users on Chrome and Firefox.

So far endpoints are set to use Google or Mozilla (depending on which browser is used) push service server like `https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/push/abc...`

I would like to host my own push service server. Is that something possible ?

Twitter and Facebook subscription endpoints are set with Google server on Chrome.

I read this page but not much information on how to implement a push service : https://w3c.github.io/push-api/#widl-ServiceWorkerRegistration-pushManager

More information :

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-thomson-webpush-vapid-02